# delete table row on JavaScript window.onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, sql-server

I have an Ecomm site using iframes.

When a user visits the site a unique identifier is created in ColdFusion on the server side of the main window. This id is written to a table so other pages can check if id is valid. I use no sessions or cookies.

All functions are inside the main page iframes so the home page stays open and never refreshed during the visit.

What I want to do is delete the user id row from the table on site exit.

On visiting the site:

I create userID and write the userID to a table. Server side.

I need to add that userID variable to a client side script something like:

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
   window.location.href = "unload.cfm?userID=";
 };
```

with unload.cfm running a Query - Delete Row on site exit.

How do I get the userID into the JavaScript? Or is there a simpler way to do this.

Note: I don't list this as a CF issue as it would be the same with any server side application.

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: You cannot change location onbeforeunload. You could try Ajax

Comment: mplungian,  i was hoping that the function (url) would be called as the page exits. I just want a way to delete userID row from table without the visitor having to do anything because they won't.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your case, but usually on websites user is allowed to login/auth with only one user at the time.

If so what you could do is store the user ip address when you create the id for him and on unload just call the unload page without any paramemters.

That way you can match the ip in the delete request with the ones you have stored and delete the appropriate user id.

Comment: Hi Chris,
This is not about login. UserID is created independent of any other function and is used to track and mutually identify any db posts in different tables. By checking if userID exists before writing to a table I can filter out some phishing attacks.

Comment: @Andy I mentioned login/auth only because this solution would work only if on the same computer all opened concurrent sessions would use same userId. Do you need to have seperate userId for each iframe/tab opened?

Comment: Chris the jS loads in the main page with the iframe within it and all functions and page navigation occur within the iframes so the main (default) page never changes nor does it see the activity within. By putting the exit jS on the main page it would always have the script and would know if the browser is closing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Return an image in the unload and do

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  document.getElementById("logged").src = "unload.cfm?userID=#userID#";
};
```

using

```
<img src="loggedin.gif" id="logged" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can read your URL and extract the desired parameter with this function call:

```
function getUrlParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```

var ID = getUrlParameter("userID")

Comment: Hi pSaadi,

I used your function with

     window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
 window.location.href = "unload.cfm?userID="var ID"" ;
     };

and all i get is userID=varID. in view source of page.